# Creating a static array class in ruby with ruby FFI

Tags: c, arrays, ruby, memory, ffi

I want to implement my own static array class in ruby. It will be an array with a fixed capacity and all elements in the array will be of a single type.
In order to have direct access to memory, I am using the FFI gem https://github.com/ffi/ffi which enables to create your own C functions and use them in your ruby program. 
I created a very simple C function that allocates memory for an array of integer and returns a pointer to the memory space :

```
int * create_static_array(int size) {
  int *arr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
  return arr;
}
```

This is my ruby static_array class that uses create_static_array :

```
require 'ffi'
class StaticArray
  attr_accessor :pointer, :capacity, :next_index
  extend FFI::Library

  ffi_lib './create_array/create_array.so'
  attach_function :create_static_array, [:int], :pointer

  def initialize(capacity)
    @capacity = capacity
    @pointer = create_static_array(capacity)
    @next_index = 0
  end
 # adds value to the next_index in array
  def push(val)
    @pointer[@next_index].write(:int, val)
    @next_index += 1
  end
 # reads value at index
  def [](index)
    raise IndexOutOfBoundException if index >= @capacity
    self.pointer[index].read(:int)
  end
 # print every value in index
  def print
    i = 0
    while (i <   @capacity)
      puts @pointer[i].read(:int)
      i += 1
    end
  end
end
```

I added a couple methods to interact with my array, push elements, read elements at index...
However my static_array instances are not exactly working as expected...

Let's say I write :

```
// creates a static array in memory which can store 4 ints
arr = StaticArray.new(4)
```

now let's push an int in our arr :

```
arr.push(20)
```

`arr.print` will output

```
20
0
0
0
```

which makes sense. Now let's push another int into arr :

```
arr.push(16)
```

and `arr.print` again :

```
4116
16
0
0
```

20 has been replaced by 4116 ... I cant really get what is going on here ?

[Here's the link to the FFIPointer class doc if that helps 
https://www.rubydoc.info/github/ffi/ffi/FFI/Pointer](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/ffi/ffi/FFI/Pointer)

Comment: What is your goal here? Performance, reduced memory use, interaction with other native code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FFI interface doesn't know about the type of your pointer, so it is just treating it as a byte array (see initialize on the pointer type). Note that while you do pass `:int`, this is to the specific `write` and `read`, not where you are doing the indexing. Thus you are writing and printing at byte offsets 0,1,2,3 rather than the integer elements at 0,4,8,12.

On a little endian system, with a 32bit, 4 byte int, the binary value of 20 is `14 00 00 00` and 16 is `10 00 00 00`.

So you allocate 4*4 bytes, so 32 bytes, the first 8 being.

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

And write 20 at offset 0

```
14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

And then write 16 at offset 1

```
14 10 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

`14 10 00 00` is `0x00001014` or 4116, and then at the next offset you print it is `10 00 00 00` which is 16.

Comment: So I have initialized an array of 16 bytes and my pointer doesn’t know the type of pointer I have initialized so when I am trying to access a particular value through index, I am actually accessing a specific byte. Then because I specify the type of value I want to read (read(:int)), the pointer understands that I want to read the all 4 bytes starting from there and compute an integer. 
From your explanations, I understand that to make my program work, I should multiply all my indexing by a factor of 4. [Github repo](https://github.com/davidgeismar/ruby-tuto-web/blob/master/dynamic_array.rb)

Comment: However I still get pretty unexpected behaviour…example :
```arr = StaticArray.new(4)
arr.print
0
-268435456
-1600786800
2047```
what a am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: `malloc` doesn't guarantee the memory is zero filled and may have something left over from previous use of the memory. Looks like it might be that.

Comment: So I dont get what malloc is for... if when you use malloc(n) 1) you re not guaranteed that you have n of free space and 2) you dont actually raise an error if you try to writte to an offset that is further than what you affected with malloc (C don’t provide any specification which deal with problem of accessing invalid index). Then what is the advantage of using malloc compare to initializing a random pointer....

Comment: 1) If `malloc(n)` returns a non-null pointer, it is guaranteed (mostly, see for example the Linux OOM killer), that you have n bytes. But it doesn't promise to set those bytes to any particular value (e.g. 0) for performance reasons (one of the common reasons to be using C). You could use say `memset` if you want to zero it. For security reasons, these days fresh (unused yet by the specific process ) from the OS is zeroed (so you can't see if it has a password from say Chrome laying around in it), but after a process creates/destroys a few things malloc will reuse memory filled with stuff.